# SASS is having issues with variables inside math.div()

Tags: sass

I'm using the new system to do divisions in SASS math.div(), and it doesn't cause me problems with the exception when I have a variable inside. I tried to use Interpolation inside the math.div, but the warning became an error and didn't compile.

[image: mah.div(error)]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem with the following expression, which was created by the sass migrator:

```scss
margin-left: calc(math.div(var(--space-s-l), -2));
margin-right: calc(math.div(var(--space-s-l), -2));
```

I ended up having to change the `math.div` calculation to multiplication:

```scss
margin-left: calc(var(--space-s-l) * -0.5);
margin-right: calc(var(--space-s-l) * -0.5);
```

In your case, you'll want to do something like:

```scss
margin-top: calc(var(track-height) * 0.25);
```

Comment: Since it's within `calc()`, you can also just use the `/` operator. Sass only complains if it's not within `calc`.